# How to delete measurement values from InfluxDb programatically?

Tags: java, spring-boot, influxdb

I am trying to delete the measurements value from the `influx` database programtically using java.

I am using [influxdb-java](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-java) to interact with the influx db, but I cannot see any command to delete the values.

Anyone have any idea how we can do this ?

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to drop a specific series, you can do the following:

```
influxDB.query(new Query("DROP SERIES FROM \"yourMeasurement\" WHERE \"yourTag\" = 'xyz'"));
```

If you would like to drop all of the measurement:

```
influxDB.query(new Query("DROP MEASUREMENT \"yourMeasurement\""));
```

However, I recommend taking a look at the documentation, you can have any query with the [influxdb-java](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-java) client from here, just pass the query as above:

[InfluxDb Query language - Delete Series](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/query_language/database_management/#delete-series-with-delete)

[InfluxDb Query language - Delete Measurements](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/query_language/database_management/#delete-measurements-with-drop-measurement)

Comment: this is not working if i am running my query programatically from java